# HMS ML Automatic Speech Recognition Not working on Huawei Mate 20 pro with EMUI 12.0.0

Tags: machine-learning, huawei-mobile-services

We got the following Error Logs when we try ASR on Huawei Mate 20 pro with EMUI 12.0.0

Important Note: We updated the Device Software using HiSuite. Before the update, the ASR was working well.

I/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: getSpeechEndTime return !isInfoGatherStart:!isInfoGatherStart !mEventsToBeReported.containsKey(taskId)true
2023-03-05 11:54:54.041 20615-21317/? E/MLASR_AsrProcessor: onFailure socket error: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference, NullPointerException
2023-03-05 11:54:54.041 20615-21317/? I/MLASR_AsrProcessor: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'long java.lang.Long.longValue()' on a null object reference isFinished=false
2023-03-05 11:54:54.041 20615-21317/? I/MLASR_AsrProcessor: onAbnormal
2023-03-05 11:54:54.042 20615-21331/? I/MLASR_AsrProcessor: InnerProcessRunnable is over
2023-03-05 11:54:54.042 20615-21317/? I/MLASR_AsrEngine: onError textLenth :17
2023-03-05 11:54:54.042 20615-21317/? I/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: handleMsg, taskId: 1678010090115222msg: 7
2023-03-05 11:54:54.042 20615-21317/? E/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: mEventsToBeReported: has no response event isInfoGatherStart:falsemsg: 7
2023-03-05 11:54:54.042 20615-21317/? I/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: handleMsg, taskId: 1678010090115222msg: 9
2023-03-05 11:54:54.042 20615-21317/? E/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: mEventsToBeReported: has no response event isInfoGatherStart:falsemsg: 9
2023-03-05 11:54:54.043 20615-21317/? I/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: handleMsg, taskId: 1678010090115222msg: 10
2023-03-05 11:54:54.043 20615-21317/? E/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: mEventsToBeReported: has no response event isInfoGatherStart:falsemsg: 10
2023-03-05 11:54:54.043 20615-21317/? I/MLASR_HaAdapter_MLKitAsr: postEvent return !isInfoGatherStart: true!mEventsToBeReported.containsKey(taskId): true
2023-03-05 11:54:54.043 20615-21316/? I/MLASR_AsrVadDetector: lowerEnergy = 40.65, energy = 51.34, diff = 0.26
2023-03-05 11:54:54.055 20615-20615/? E/AsrProcessor: onError code : 11203, message : 1003, Service unavailable

It didn't work after update this devices software but It is working on other devices.

Answer (score -1):

It fixed after We upgraded SDKs from version 2 to 3 as the following:

// Speech to Text (Automatic speech recognition)

implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-voice-asr-plugin:3.9.0.300'

implementation 'com.huawei.hms:ml-computer-voice-asr:3.9.0.300'